# JSF property initialization

Tags: java, jsf, initialization

I came across the following issue:
I have the following JSF bean:

```
public class MailingBean {
    private RecipientService<?> recipientService;
    private SearchRecipientController searchRecipientController = new SearchRecipientController(recipientService);

    //Stuff, GET, SET
}
```

That bean's intialized in the `faces-config.xml` as follows:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>mailingBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>path.to.package.MailingBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>recipientService</property-name>
        <value>#{playerService}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

The thins is when `new SearchRecipientController(recipientService)` is invoking, `recipientService` is null. Is it possible to specify initialization order in some way? Or how can I fix that?

Comment: Do you have setter for the property `recipientService`?

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj Sure, I do. I just didn't write them explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the managed property in the constructor(or as in your case in declaration). You should use a postconstruct method for what you are trying to do. The manage property is set after the object is constructed.

```
private SearchRecipientController searchRecipientController;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
     searchRecipientController = new SearchRecipientController(getRecipientService());
}
```

Another way would be to use the searchRecipientController only via getter.

```
public SearchRecipientController getSearchRecipientController(){
    if(searchRecipientController==null){
        searchRecipientController = new SearchRecipientController(getRecipientService());
    }
    return searchRecipientController;
}
```